# How to use stub.getTransient() in Node Chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I have a chaincode written in node.js and I am trying to read transient values but it's not working properly:

my code:

```
let secretData = stub.getTransient(); 
let value = secretData.get('privayeKey').toBuffer().toString('utf8')
```

`value` is not correct. Some random characters appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's base64 not utf8. So code is

```
et secretData = stub.getTransient(); 
let value = secretData.get('privayeKey').toBuffer().toString('base64')
```

Comment: Hi @Narayan.  I tried to use your sample code.  The original value I used is "this represents a secret data", but when I retrieved the data using the sample code I got the following: "thisrepresentsasecretdat"